# Effect of Log change of scale on $\delta$ distribution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, distribution-theory

I am aware of the multiplicative adjustment when dilating a $\delta$-distribution:
$$\delta(ax)=\frac{1}{a}\delta(x), a>0 $$

Suppose we would like to map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_+$ under $x\to\log(x)$ how does $\delta$ change under the change?

As the origin maps to $x=1$ we should have a $\delta$ centered at $x=1$, but is there also a multiplicative adjustment?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a differentiable function $f$ with zeros $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, i.e. $f(x_1)=\ldots=f(x_n)=0$, the following equation holds:

$$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{|f'(x_n)|} \delta(x-x_n)$$

(See also [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function))

Thus,

$$\delta(\log(x)) = \frac{1}{|\log'(1)|}\delta(x-1)$$

Comment: thanks. as a followup, to go the other way: suppose our $\delta(x-a)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and we would like to send $x\to e^x$ we then have $\frac{1}{|e^a|'}\delta(x-log(a))$?

Comment: im sorry @Andreas, apparently i don't have enough reputation to upvote

Comment: @teddy Barring unconventional notation, yes.

Comment: i am questioning my first comment about $x\to e^x$. what is the purpose of the locations of the zeros $x_1,...,x_n$? is the scaling factor really $e^{-a}$?