# Delta distribution composition with exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

this is a followup question to : [Effect of Log change of scale on $\delta$ distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526683/effect-of-log-change-of-scale-on-delta-distribution)

the examples that iv'e seen of composition of a delta function with another function somehow use the zeros of the additional function. given that, it makes sense that composing $$\delta( log(x)) = \frac{1}{|log'(1)|}\delta(x-1)$$
where we map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$

What is the proper expression if we want to go the other way? suppose we have a shifted delta, $\delta(x-1)$, valid on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and we would like to send $x\to e^x$, what is the proper multiplier on the new delta (and what is the justification)? it makes sense that $\delta(x-1)\to \delta(x-\log(1))=\delta(x)$, but what is the multiplicative adjustment?

thank you

Comment: Let $f=e^x$.  Inasmuch as $e^x\ne 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\delta \circ f\equiv 0$.  If instead, $f(x)=e^x-1$, then $\delta \circ f=\delta$.

Comment: thanks @MarkViola. shouldn't there be a multiplicative adjustment to $\delta\circ f=\delta$? $\frac{1}{|e'|}$ on the right?

Comment: You're welocme.  The derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$.  And $e^x$ at $x=0$ is $e^0=1$.